# Help with correction of writing SQL queries

Tags: mysql, query

I have questions, but i never work with SQL before. Can someone help with queries?

**1)** "How many persons with Title = 'Mr' [1] have 'Purchasing Manager' type [2] of the contract [3]"

**2)** Find email addresses dbo.[1] that are not associated with any person dbo.[2]. Return [EmailAddress] and [EmailAddressID] from the table dbo.[1]

Provide different requests using LEFT, RIGHT JOINs and without joining tables

**3)** Delete from dbo.[1] the rows with the 'ID' are multiple of 10

**4)** Find and return the list of Man [Human] greater than average

My answers:

**1)** SELECT 'Mr' FROM Title WHERE 'Mr' = Purchasing Manager FROM 2

**2)** SELECT * FROM 1 WHERE 2 NOT LIKE 1. SELECT EmailAddress, EmailAddressID FROM 1

**3)** DELETE Rows = 'ID' FROM 1 WHERE Rows = *10

**4)** SELECT Man FROM * Human WHERE Man > (SELECT AVG(Man) FROM * Human)

Comment: Please provide the table DDL for your questions. Homework is not off-topic here but you should tell people that your question is study related. There are a number of articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to look? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  This question will likely be closed because it's currently much too localized (e.g. not useful for a larger audience).  I would suggest you check this [meta question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) first for some answers to your general query questions and then rewrite this question to ask about any specific issues that you are still running into.

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE Title = 'Mr' AND type = 'Purchasing Manager';
-- I don't know what `contract` means; perhaps it is another table??
```

3.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE (ID % 10) = 0;4
```

"dbo" is not a MySQL concept.  Brackets are not used.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.